# C basic - called object is not a function or function pointer

Tags: c

That's my code -

```
main() 
{

    double x;
    double y = pow(((1/3 + sin(x/2))(pow(x, 3) + 3)), 1/3);
    printf("%f", y);

    return 0;
}
```

I get an error in `double y = pow((1/3 + sin(x/2))(pow(x, 3) + 3), 1/3);`, it says that called object is not a function or function pointer. I don't get it though - `(1/3 + sin(x/2))(pow(x, 3) + 3)` is the first element of `pow(x, y);` that is the x I want to raise to y (1/3) power. Where lies the problem? I'm pretty new to c basic but I can't find the answer anywhere.

Comment: Besides your strange syntax causing the error, you should know that `1/3` is integer division, equal to zero.

Comment: what's wrong with the syntax though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to multiply, you need to use the `*` operator.  You can't put parenthesized expressions adjacent to each other to denote multiplication.

```
(1/3 + sin(x/2))*(pow(x, 3) + 3)
```

Comment: @ImReallyBadAtCoding glad I could help.  Feel free to accept this answer if you found it useful.

Comment: Sure! Just one more thing though - pow(x, y/z) always returns 1 to me - is there any function that works like sqrt but lets me choose my own root?

Comment: @ImReallyBadAtCoding that's because you're doing integer division.  Use `1.0/3` to force floating point division.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the return value of `pow` is a double, not a function. Maybe what you're trying to do is pass a call to `pow` as the second argument to the first pow.

Comment: Yeah, but what's the problem then? I want y to return the double value of the pow function.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h> // For pow() function

int main() {

    // Initialize with whatever value you want
    double x = 100;

    // Make sure to use an arithmetic operator
    double y = pow(((1/3.0 + sin(x/2))*(pow(x, 3) + 3)), 1/3.0);

    // Use right format specifier
    printf("%lf", y);

    return 0;
}
```

1. Don't forget to include `math.h` library.
2. Initialize `x` with a value.
3. Avoid using integer division `1/3`, instead use `1/3.0` or `1.0/3.0` because `1/3 == 0`.
4. Use an arithmetic operator (`+`, `-`, `*`, `/`) before middle `pow()` like `pow(((1/3.0 + sin(x/2))+(pow(x, 3) + 3)), 1/3.0)`.
5. (Opt.) Use right format specifier for `y` which is `%lf`. But you may get away with `%f`.